# Why are large numpy arrays 64-byte aligned but not smaller ones

Tags: numpy

The following code:

```
prev=[]
addresses=[]
for i in range(10000):
    a = np.ones(x).astype(np.float32)
    prev.append(a)
    address = a.__array_interface__['data'][0]
    assert(address % 64 == 0)
    assert((address not in addresses))
    addresses.append(address)
```

Will not raise an `assertionError` for values of x > 252 suggesting that arrays bigger than 253, (or bigger than 505 when using float16) are aligned differently to smaller arrays. What is the reason for this?

I am on a OSX (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6920HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz) running `numpy 1.12.1`

Comment: Could it be just pure chance? What happens if you print instead of asserting?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - no the chance is less than one in ten thousand (that's the purpose of the outer loop)

Comment: But you break out of the loop the moment one assertion fails. Keep going to see what happens.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think you're missing the purpose of the assertion - it *doesn't* fail with large arrays (meaning that they are always 64-byte aligned)  and always fails with smaller arrays. Once the assertion fails it has been proven that an array is not 64-byte aligned and there is no need to carry on.

Comment: Maybe small arrays use recycled memory, while large ones require a fresh OS request.

Answer (score 2):

Your test loop isn't accomplishing exactly what you expect.  Since only one array exists in memory at a time, it's quite possible - indeed LIKELY - that new ones will be allocated at the same memory address as the one just freed.  You'd have to do something like append the arrays to a list (thus making them all exist in memory simultaneously) to actually test 10000 distinct allocations.

However, I can easily believe that you're seeing a real effect, as it's perfectly reasonable for a memory allocator to use different strategies based on the size of the block being allocated.  For example, at some point the allocator may stop trying to use memory it already has, and start requesting entire memory pages directly from the operating system.  Once that threshold is reached, you'd find that everything is aligned on a much higher power-of-2 boundary than 64 - perhaps 4096.  You seem to be hitting some intermediate threshold at 1024 bytes (including overhead), it might be interesting to test for 128/256/512/1024 byte alignment.

Comment: You make a good point regarding address reuse, I modified the code in my question to exclude that possibility.

Comment: I did what you suggested regarding trying different alignments and it becomes more interesting - there is another alignment at 512, and then for even bigger arrays 1024.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess: Using aligned memory typically involves allocating a larger block, and then releasing the upfront bytes that are allocated before the alignment boundary.

This is insignificant for large arrays, but for small arrays the fragmentation and overhead introduced likely outweights the benefits.

Comment: what are the benefits?

Comment: Cache lines are read in aligned blocks; so an aligned array requires fewer cache line reads and storage than a non-aligned array. Also, memory mapping only works for aligned memory blocks on most platforms, i think. There are probably other reasons too.